# What is the number next to the "review answer/question" button?

Tags: support, review-page

What's the number next the "review answer/question" button?

[image: Number next to review answer button]
Is it the number of people who have reviewed the question/answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the quality of the post; the number of users who already reviewed it is not shown.

The quality number can be a negative or a positive number; the highest number I have seen is 79 (in the "low quality posts" tab for the review page), and the lowest is −7. As negative numbers are used, I think that the higher the number is, the higher is the post's quality.

Comment: So, what does that exactly mean? So a post w/ 73 is better/worse than a post w/ 100?

Comment: I expanded the answer: A post with a quality of 100 is better than a post with a quality of 73.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure that out?

Comment: How is the quality number calculated? Why isn't voting up/down enough?

Comment: @daviesgeek I keep reading on Meta Stack Overflow. `:-)`

Comment: @Matt As a matter of fact, there are some answers that are marked as low quality, and that are perfectly fine for the question being asked; they are one-line answers, but their presence could mean the question is not acceptable. Suppose somebody replies with "Yes." It could be the answer should be expanded, or it could be that is the only answer possible for the question; in the latter case, it is probable the question should be closed. As far as I know, how the quality is calculated is not known. Maybe there are posts/comments about that, but not detailed.